# File Open dialog freezing on macOS 10.12

Tags: finder, macos, performance

I recently updated my macbook pro to macos 10.12. After I'm facing a lot of problems with file access.

1. Whenever I try to save or open a file, the "File Open" dialog comes after 30-60 seconds. Till then I'll not able to do anything on the application. But other apps work fine.
2. File->Open Recent is also taking the same amount of time. I've no option other than waiting for it load.
3. Whenever I try to drag and drop a file it is not easier. As mentioned even this takes same time.

I think the above problems are associated with a common issue in the OS. Please let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: What program are you using? My imac has the same problem,which finally turned to be folder privilege issue

Comment: My issue is with all applications. When I try saving a web page, downloading a file, the file open dialog freezes. It is with every application.

Comment: Better have a screen capture of folder info(Sharing&permission Part) of the folder(Users/Your currentuser folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be associated with iCloud drive. Here are two steps to resolve.

1. I seem to have resolved the freezing dialog box problem by disabling iCloud Drive. I have been experiencing what seem to be exactly the same problems, even after two fresh Sierra installs.
2. If you don't want to disable iCloud drive, use Finder-> Preferences-> Sidebar- Disable iCloud drive to  remove the iCloud option on the Finder sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

Spotlight indexing may be the issue.
Add cloud drives as exceptions to spotlight indexing:
[image]